# Звідки з'явились слова «ясен Світ» в колядці «Ой, радуйся, Земле»

Tags: етимологія, історія-мови, колядки

[«Україна молода» пише](https://www.umoloda.kiev.ua/number/3255/164/119081/)

> Зокрема, всім відома колядка «Ой, радуйся, Земле», продовжувалася словами «ясен Світ народився» або «новий день народився».

Але ніякого обґрунтування цьому твердженню не дає.

Ще знайшов такі варіанти на [lyricstranslate](https://lyricstranslate.com/uk/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%96%D1%80-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%96-ii-good-evening-you.html):

> 1. Ой радуйся Земле Син Божий народився!
> 2. Ой радуйся Земле Ясен Світ засвітився!
> 3. Ой радуйся Земле Світ Новий народився!
> 4. Ой радуйтесь Люде Ясен Світ засвітився!

Цікавить звідки пішов вираз *Ясен Світ*. Чи пов'язано це з тим, що християнські вірування замінили дохристиянські світотворчі вірування чи це вже пізніше утворення?

Ось приклад космогонічної колядки - [Ой як то ще було із нащада світа.](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%BA_%D1%82%D0%BE_%D1%89%D0%B5_%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%96%D0%B7_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B0)